# Does Linq have a startup penalty?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I need to either use Linq queries or iterate data 100,000+ in a app. Speed will be essential. I wrote a test and didn't get the results I expected. Basically I feed the exact same data to two different functions in a loop 100 times. The functions are similar except that in one I use multiple Linq queries and in the other I iterate the data manually to build the info. The code looks like this:

**Linq version:**

```
            //Get max and min of each
        double maxX = (from node in pointCloud
                       select node.Node.Value.X).Max();
        double maxY = (from node in pointCloud
                       select node.Node.Value.Y).Max();
        double maxZ = (from node in pointCloud
                       select node.Node.Value.Z).Max();
        double minX = (from node in pointCloud
                       select node.Node.Value.X).Min();
        double minY = (from node in pointCloud
                       select node.Node.Value.Y).Min();
        double minZ = (from node in pointCloud
                       select node.Node.Value.Z).Min();
        //Extract all the x, y and z values into arrays
        double[] x = (from node in pointCloud
                      select node.Node.Value.X).ToArray();
        double[] y = (from node in pointCloud
                      select node.Node.Value.Y).ToArray();
        double[] z = (from node in pointCloud
                      select node.Node.Value.Z).ToArray();
```

VS:

**Manual version:**

```
        //Get max and min of each
        double maxX = double.MinValue;
        double maxY = double.MinValue;
        double maxZ = double.MinValue;
        double minX = double.MaxValue;
        double minY = double.MaxValue;
        double minZ = double.MaxValue;

        List<double> x = new List<double>();
        List<double> y = new List<double>();
        List<double> z = new List<double>();

        foreach (NodeDistance<KDTreeNode<g.Point3d>> node in pointCloud)
        {
            maxX = msf.Max(maxX, node.Node.Value.X);
            maxY = msf.Max(maxY, node.Node.Value.Y);
            maxZ = msf.Max(maxZ, node.Node.Value.Z);
            minX = msf.Min(minX, node.Node.Value.X);
            minY = msf.Min(minY, node.Node.Value.Y);
            minZ = msf.Min(minZ, node.Node.Value.Z);
            x.Add(node.Node.Value.X);
            y.Add(node.Node.Value.Y);
            z.Add(node.Node.Value.Z);
        }
```

Here is the puzzle. When the Linq version runs it takes a lot longer the first time. I start the stopwatch before I begin the loop and then write the elapsed time after each time the function is run. Here is the first 5 times the Linq function runs:

```
00:00:00.0425169 (after 1st run)
00:00:00.0433850
00:00:00.0437312
00:00:00.0440666
00:00:00.0443969
....
00:00:00.1352192 (Total time for all 100 executions)
```

When I run the manually iterated version the first five times look like this:

```
00:00:00.0124269 (after 1st run)
00:00:00.0138497
00:00:00.0152502
00:00:00.0166348
00:00:00.0180180
....
00:00:00.1060389 (Total time for all 100 executions)
```

I will have 30 or 40 different Linq queries that will be run at various times. The data is not all queued up and the same query runs over and over. If I run a Linq query and then do other stull and it takes essentially 0.04 seconds each time I run the query then the app will be really slow. If it takes 0.04 seconds the first time ANY Linq query runs and then that time does not happen again for that app then it will be better to use Linq.

Does someone have experience with Linq vs manual iteration and have some guidance between the two regarding speed?

Comment: Your test doesn't seem particularly fair. The manual version will be faster because you're only going through the loop a single time, not 9 times like in your LINQ code. It's like sending your friend to the supermarket 9 times, once for each item vs sending them to the supermarket once with a shopping list of 9 items.

Comment: Look if you want to save your self IL, don't use linq, it has extra checks and balances, there is more stack allocations as it jumps through more methods to do what it needs to do. However all this totally put aside. The speed difference is because in the first you are iterating pointCloud x times, in the second only once.

Comment: Q: Does LINQ have a startup penalty? A: No.  Q:Can LINQ incur performance penalties?  A: Sometimes, yes.  But I think the problem here is simply that your benchmarks aren't equivalent - you're comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: `Q: Does LINQ have a startup penalty? A: No.` Based on http://joeduffyblog.com/2011/10/23/on-generics-and-some-of-the-associated-overheads/ I would assume the first invocation would have some (small) compilation cost. I may be incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of any instances where "straight C#" wouldn't be *at least* as fast as LINQ.  There are definitely possibilities where LINQ could be appreciably *slower*.

So if "speed" is critical ... then you might be better off not using LINQ expressions.

IMPORTANT POINTS:

1. Be sure to benchmark

   <= I'm not sure your example above is really a valid benchmark
2. Be sure to benchmark with *large data sets*

   <= I encountered a very innocent-looking LINQ expression a couple of years ago (written by somebody else) that looked OK ... and performed well for a handful of items ... but became exponentially slower, and ultimately blew up with a stack overflow (no pun intended) ... with 1000s of items...

Comment: Great tips @paulsm4.

Comment: The other thing to consider when benchmarking is that you should **ignore** startup costs. If you are benchmarking something, run through it twice, timing only the second invocation. You don't want to consider assembly load times or JIT costs in your calculations

Comment: Another one, is to build the Release version of the application and test the `.exe`, not the VS IDE. `StringBuilder`, for example, performs way worse in the VS environment (no matter the build type) than in the final `.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> The data is not all queued up and the same query runs over and over.

If you will execute a LINQ query several times with the same input, it is wiser to save the results.

```
var cityGroups = persons.GroupBy (person => person.City);
```

If you look at the [references source of Enumerable.GroupBy](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,f4b894c2a2ce16e2) You'll see that when you ask for the first element, the complete source sequence is enumerated to put the items in a Lookup table. So if you enumerate again, the Lookup table will be created again:

So if you have to enumerate several times, it is wise to execute the query and store the results in a way that will enhance efficiency when enumerating again:

```
var result = cityGroups.ToList();
foreach (var cityGroup in cityGroups)
{
    DoSomething(cityGroup};
}
foreach (var cityGroup in cityGroups)
{
     DoSomethinElse(cityGroup);
}
```

Even if you won't just enumerate, but add some LINQ statements after it, it might be wise to save the intermediate results:

```
var newYorkers = cityGroups.Where(cityGroup => cityGroup.Key == "New York").ToList();
var ghostTowns = cityGroups.Where(cityGroup => !cityGroup.Any()).ToList();
```

The lookup table will be created twice. If yo do a ToList() before you extend the result the lookup table will be created only once

```
var result = cityGroups.ToList();
var newYorkers = result.Where(cityGroup => cityGroup.Key == "New York").ToList();
var ghostTowns = result.Where(cityGroup => !cityGroup.Any()).ToList();
```

My advice would be: if you will be performing the same query over and over again, do a ToList (or To-whatever-you-need).